# webpack css-loader doesn't work as expected with karma

Tags: javascript, build, webpack, karma-runner, css-loader

I'm using [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) `Local Scope` feature, and having a bit trouble with it.
I'm writing a directive for `Vue.js`.
This directive is importing a `scss` file and using the exported classes created by the loader to assign it to some elements the directive is creating.
This works when I build for `prod/dev`, but when I build for `test` it doesn't work.
I import my directive file, and I test one of the directive functions by creating a dom element using `jQuery`, and then assign it the class the `css-loader` exported. I use `karma` for testing, so when I launch the `karma` server in my browser to debug the test, I see the elements are assigned the classes, but they have no styling whatsoever. I am suspecting my `webpack` config for my `test` environment is at fault.
This is my `webpack` config for my `test` environment:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint'
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: 'style',
          loader: 'css!sass!postcss'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
  ],
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      sass: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css!sass")
    }
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

And then I use it with karma config file:

```
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');

module.exports = function (config) {
  const configuration = {
    basePath: '../',
    singleRun: false,
    autoWatch: true,
    logLevel: 'INFO',
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'test-reports'
    },
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
    ],
    frameworks: [
      'jasmine'
    ],
    files: [
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      conf.path.src('app.spec.js')
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      [conf.path.src('app.spec.js')]: [
        'webpack'
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    coverageReporter: {
      type: 'html',
      dir: 'coverage/'
    },
    webpack: require('./webpack-test.conf'),
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-shim'),
      require('karma-webpack')
    ]
  };

  config.set(configuration);
};
```

Here's my directive, importing the scss file:

```
import classes from '../../css/directives/tooltip.scss';

const TOOLTIP_CLASS = classes.tooltip;
const TOOLTIP_ARROW_CLASS = classes.arrow;
```

And then I use it in my test to assign the classes for test created dom elements:

```
...
const $arrow = $(document.createElement('span'));
$arrow.addClass(TooltipRewireAPI.__get__('TOOLTIP_ARROW_CLASS'));
...
```

So the classes are assigned, but I don't see any `style.css` like specified in the [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) of `webpack` with my styles, and no styles are actually applied to my test created dom elements. Anyone got an idea what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [not supported](https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack/issues/133).
I used style loader instead for my tests.